# NullReferenceException vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

i am getting an error as "object reference not set to an instance of an object"
in the third line of this code.
what are the possible reasons?

```
Dim table As New DataTable()
Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table
Me.bindingSource1 = DataGridView1.DataSource
table = Me.bindingSource1.DataSource
```

i just need to know the possible reasons

Answer (score 0):

Either "Me" is null (nothing in VB) or DataGridView1 is null. The reasons for this are probably somewhere else in your code. Use the debugger to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `DataGridView1` might be `nothing`, There is no problem with `Me` because the execution crossed the second line with out any interrupt. check whether `DataGridView1` is nothing or not.

- Set a `break point` on the line 3.
- while the `break point` strikes, press `Ctrl+I` (Immediate Window)
- Type `?DataGridView1` in that.
- And press `ENTER`, you will find whether it is `nothing` or not.